# Regex to match all the occurences within 2 strings + Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to match and replace the backslash \ with forwardslash / between 2 specific words using java. I tried this and it works fine in regex tester https://regexr.com/474s0 but not working when I test from a java based application; getting this error.

org.apache.oro.text.regex.MalformedPatternException: Sequence (?<...) not recognized

**Regex tried :** `(?<=<(DocumentImagePath)>.*?)(\\)(?=.*<\/(DocumentImagePath)>)`

**Sample :**

`<DocumentImagePath>95230-88\M0010002F.tif\test</DocumentImagePath>
<DocumentImagePath>123-88\M0010002F.tif\test</DocumentImagePath>
<DocumentImagePath>abc-88\M0010002F.tif\test</DocumentImagePath>`

Any help is appreciated.

Note : I understand the positive look behind is not supported in all compilers but looking for a suitable replacement regex which works in Java.

Comment: It would help if you'd post the Java code you're using. I'm not sure how you're matching all of the backslashes on each line. My approach would be to use a regex to match all of the text between the start and end tag, then use String.replaceAll to replace the backslashes with forward slashes in that string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this (Java 9+):

```
String sample = "<DocumentImagePath>95230-88\\M0010002F.tif\\test</DocumentImagePath>\r\n" +
                "95230-88\\M0010002F.tif\\test\r\n" +
                "<DocumentImagePath>123-88\\M0010002F.tif\\test</DocumentImagePath>\r\n" +
                "<DocumentImagePath>abc-88\\M0010002F.tif\\test</DocumentImagePath>\r\n";

String result = Pattern.compile("<DocumentImagePath>.*?</DocumentImagePath>")
                       .matcher(sample)
                       .replaceAll(r -> r.group().replace('\\', '/'));

System.out.println(result);
```

*Output*

```
<DocumentImagePath>95230-88/M0010002F.tif/test</DocumentImagePath>
95230-88\M0010002F.tif\test
<DocumentImagePath>123-88/M0010002F.tif/test</DocumentImagePath>
<DocumentImagePath>abc-88/M0010002F.tif/test</DocumentImagePath>
```

**UPDATE:** For Java 8 and earlier, use this code:

```
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("<DocumentImagePath>.*?</DocumentImagePath>").matcher(sample);
while (m.find())
    m.appendReplacement(buf, m.group().replace('\\', '/'));
String result = m.appendTail(buf).toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Im seeing this error "The target type of this expression must be a functional interface" , not very good in lambda expressions to solve on my own. BTW using Java 8.